# Valgrind in Eclipse. Valgrind integration has been disabled in Preferences

Tags: c, linux, eclipse, valgrind, development-environment

I have installed Valgrind in my Ubuntu machine , Eclipse IDE. When I tried to make new profile configuration of existing C project , Profile As >>Profile with Valgrind, I got message `Valgrind integration has been disabled in Preferences`. How to fix this error?

Comment: @haccks - I'm not sure about that. It's an actual problem faced with a software development tool, that's acceptable according to the FAQ... I will give you however that there is no apparent research effort.

Comment: What versions of Eclipse and Valgrind do you have installed? What Ubuntu version are you running? Have you read this page: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Linux_Tools_Project/Valgrind/User_Guide

Comment: @Mike; OK. Retracted my vote.